# Ajax request showing browser response data but how i can var_dump data in controller function in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Route File

```
Route::post('/like',[
    'uses'=>'postController@postLikePost','as'=>'like'

]);
```

Ajax  Request File

```
var  token = '{{Session::token() }}';
var urlLike = '{{ route('like') }}';

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.like').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     //dataset  use  for  take  close  data
     postId = $(this).closest("[data-postid]").data().postid;
    var isLike = event.target.previousElementSibling == null;
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url:urlLike,
      data: {  isLke: isLike, postId: postId, _token:token },
    })
     .done( function () {
     });
  });
  });
```

Controller Function

```
public  function postLikePost(Request $request){

          $post_id= $request['postId'];

          dd($post_id);

}
```

[image]

My  request  data  is  displaying  in  response  but  when  i  am  trying  to  save  that  data  in  controller  function.Nothing  happen  after  that i  just  trying  to  see  the  dumping  data.  but  I  don't  know  how  i can see that  dump data  as  ajax  dot  go  any  url. Now  just  i want to  see dump  data  in  controller  function . How i can  do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. Here's a solution that worked great for me!

In your controller you can do this:

```
public function postLikePost(Request $request){

  $post_id = $request->get('postId');

}
```

Hope it helps!